# Debugging a site using web service with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: debugging, web-services

I've got a solution with many projects
One of these proejcts is a "MyProject.Web" web application.

This has a web reference to MyProject.WebService" project -

I have a breakpoint in the WebService project, and i call the method on one of my Web forms, the break point is not hit....

How can i enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the solution and choose "Set Startup Projects".  Choose to start multiple projects and select both your web site and web service to start with debugging.  Then when you start the debugger they will both fire up and you should have full debugging in both.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too a while back and this is what I followed:
http://dansen.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/debugging-wcf-clients-and-services/

> Visual Studio has feature that
>   supports attaching to multiple
>   projects when starting up.
>
> In this example, I have a WCF service
>   hosted in IIS which lives in the
>   Wcf.Demo.IisServiceHost project. I
>   also have a Wcf.Demo.TestHarness
>   project which calls the service. I
>   want to be able to attach the debugger
>   to both the client and service by
>   simply pressing F5.